# Why shouldn't you edit in a replicated database

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, replication

Say you replicate a database to another database. Are there any reasons you wouldn't want to edit your replicated data other than having different data in the replica database than in the database you replicated from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not edit a child in one-way replication, because if you are editing the child table the edits will be overwritten upon next the synchronization. The whole point of the replica is to synchronize (overwrite) the child with the parent on a scheduled or on-demand basis.

[ESRI Replication Types Description](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/geodatabases/replication-types.htm#GUID-C8015A19-EDA8-4D26-B32B-EB11C5AE191E)

If you are using two-way replication then what you described is a feasible editor workflow, but the context of your question makes me think you are talking about one-way.